# mysql - illegal mix of collations with nested selects

Tags: mysql, collation

I have a MySQL query, with a few nested selects. the  as below:

my inner query, returns two columns:

```
     ` MIN( PreQuery.updatetime ) as InTime`

      `MAX( PreQuery.updatetime ) as OutTime`
```

These are in a datetime format, `2013-03-22 12:04:06`

I want to return only datetime's within the last 26 hours so use where clause:
`'InTime'>  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 26 HOUR)`

This returns error:
`#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '>'`

any ideas on how I can correct this or display data from last 26 hours only? Thanks as always.

```
select * from (select
      PreQuery.callingname,
      PreQuery.geofence,
      PreQuery.GroupSeq,
      MIN( PreQuery.`updatetime` ) as InTime,
      MAX( PreQuery.`updatetime` ) as OutTime
   from
     ( select
              v_starting.callingname,
              v_starting.geofence,
              v_starting.`updatetime`,
              @lastGroup := @lastGroup + if( @lastAddress = v_starting.geofence 
                                         AND @lastVehicle = v_starting.callingname, 0, 1 ) as GroupSeq,
              @lastVehicle := v_starting.callingname as justVarVehicleChange,
              @lastAddress := v_starting.geofence as justVarAddressChange
           from
              v_starting,
              ( select @lastVehicle := '',
                       @lastAddress := '',
                       @lastGroup := 0 ) SQLVars
           order by
              v_starting.`updatetime` ) PreQuery
   Group By
      PreQuery.callingname,
      PreQuery.geofence,
      PreQuery.GroupSeq) parent

      where geofence <>'' and 'InTime'>  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 26 HOUR)
```

Comment: For start, what you could do is set the same collation on every table in the query.

Comment: Thanks but only one table being referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the apostrophes around `InTime`, i.e.

```
where geofence <>'' and InTime >  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 26 HOUR)
```